# How to Merge 2 Queries in 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have these 2 SQL queries that i need to join.

Query1 (Shows the list of Entiries):

```
SELECT
  E.EntityId
  ,E.EntityNo 
  , E.Name
  , E.ShortName
FROM [xx].[xx].[Entities] E
WHERE
  E.Type = 'A'  
  AND E.YearEndMonth = 6
```

Query2 (Shows list of Contacts):

```
SELECT P.Firstname,P.LastName, P.Email
FROM [xxx].[xx].[People] P
WHERE P.PeopleId= (
  SELECT TOP 1 A.PeopleId
  FROM [xxx].[xx].[EntityAttentions] A
  WHERE A.EntityId = ?
  ORDER BY A.EntityAttentionTypeId ASC
)
```

My Objective is to have a combined list of Entities and Contact people.

I tried this but with a have error (Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS)

```
SELECT
  E.EntityId
  ,E.EntityNo 
  , E.Name
  , E.ShortName
  ,
  (SELECT P.Firstname,P.LastName, P.Email
  FROM [xxx].[xx].[People] P
  WHERE P.PeopleId= (
      SELECT  TOP 1 A.PeopleId
      FROM [xxx].[xx].[EntityAttentions] A
      WHERE A.EntityId = E.EntityId
      ORDER BY A.EntityAttentionTypeId ASC
      )
  )
FROM [xxx].[xx].[Entities] E
WHERE
  E.Type = 'A'  
  AND E.YearEndMonth = 6;
```

I guess I must use some kind of JOIN but don't know exactly what to do.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT
  E.EntityId
  ,E.EntityNo 
  , E.Name
  , E.ShortName  
  , B.Firstname,B.LastName, B.Email
FROM [xxx].[xx].[Entities] E
CROSS APPLY
(     SELECT P.Firstname,P.LastName, P.Email
      FROM [xxx].[xx].[People] P
      WHERE P.PeopleId= 
        (
          SELECT  TOP 1 A.PeopleId
          FROM [xxx].[xx].[EntityAttentions] A
          WHERE A.EntityId = E.EntityId
          ORDER BY A.EntityAttentionTypeId ASC
        )
 ) B
WHERE
  E.Type = 'A'  
  AND E.YearEndMonth = 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
    E.EntityId
  , E.EntityNo 
  , E.Name
  , E.ShortName
  , P.*
FROM [xxx].[xx].[Entities] E
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT P.Firstname,P.LastName, P.Email
    FROM [xxx].[xx].[People] P
    WHERE P.PeopleId = (
      SELECT TOP 1 A.PeopleId
      FROM [xxx].[xx].[EntityAttentions] A
      WHERE A.EntityId = E.EntityId
      ORDER BY A.EntityAttentionTypeId
    )
) P
WHERE E.Type = 'A'  
  AND E.YearEndMonth = 6;
```

Comment: Hi, Do we need to use cross apply or outer apply?

Comment: In this case OUTER APPLY more desirable to use.

Comment: This returns all People, i need to return the TOP 1

Comment: @Sivakumar, and now there is no difference between CROSS/OUTER APPLY.

Comment: @Sivakumar and Devart - Whats the difference performance wise of CROSS  and OUTER APPLY?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy, in your case - no difference, but theoretically OUTER APPLY construction works faster for 1:1, but not always.